# How to Read specific hidden field value in WebResponse

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I have a situation where i got full HTML page HTML in a string using WebResponse Now I have to read a Hidden Field Value from that Response Can you suggest me some good ways to get specific Hidden Fields value ??

Answer (score 0):

You could use an HTML parser such as [`HTML Agility Pack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Once you feed the raw string into it, you can query the DOM and find elements by id or type for example.

Comment: Can You Please Post Some Example ??

Comment: Did you check the documentation: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples